# gunicorn modul not found django heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

first time deploying to heroku. I got the test app deployed and I ran the migrations fine. However, I got the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djorg2'
```

I ran heroku logs --tail and got the following result here

[image]

here is the a pic of my file paths

[image]

and here is my current Procfile

```
web: gunicorn djorg2.wsgi --log-file -
```

I'm a little new to deploying on heroku. Does anyone know what my problem might be and/or count point me in the right direction. I been trying to trouble shoot this for the good part of an afternoon and I'm a little stuck.

Comment: are you running that command on `practice` folder. if not that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
web: gunicorn practice.djorg2.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips everyone. I had a feeling it was probably due to file placement. I re-organized my files so that everything was at the root of my git repo and it works fine now.

[image]

I think I'm going to put everything in its own file location from now on just to be more organized and not confuse myself. I did try

```
web: gunicorn practice.djorg2.wsgi --log-file -
```

but for some weird reason it didn't work.